Estimate Jaccard of two sets from two samples
Imagine I have two sets and I begin sampling from each of them. How can I extrapolate the overlap from the samples to the full sets?
Concrete example: say I have a 1% sample of 1M elements from Set A (100M elements total) and a .33% sample from Set B of 1M elements (300M elements total in Set B). If I learn that there is a 350,000 overlap between these two samples from A and B, how do I extrapolate that to estimate the overlap of the non-sampled sets?
I came across Estimate Jaccard similarity based on a sample but my question is slightly different as the sampling ratio for each subset could be different and the sets could be vastly different in size.
Using the formula from the edit in that post: =|∩|
we can estimate ∪=||+||−≈|′|+|′|+ and the estimator for the Jaccard would: _(′,′)=/(|′|/+|'|/+)
I would have L = 350000/(.0033 * .01)  and then est_jaccard(A,B) = 350000/(.0033 * .01) / (1,000,000 / .01) + (1000000/.0033) + 350000/(.0033 * .01)) = 96%. This is obviously wrong, what am I missing here?
